# Docker multiple networks, unable to connect outside world

Tags: docker, macos, networking, docker-compose

When deploying docker-compose with multiple networks, only the first interface have an access to the outside world

```
version: "3.9"
services:
  speedtest:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: speedtest.Dockerfile
    tty: true
    networks:
      - eth0
      - eth1

networks:
  eth0:
  eth1:
```

Running inside the container ping for example `ping -I eth0 google.com` works fine
However running `ping -I eth1 google.com` will get the result

```
PING google.com (142.250.200.238) from 172.21.0.2 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From c4d3b238f9a1 (172.21.0.2) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From c4d3b238f9a1 (172.21.0.2) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
```

Any idea how to have egress to the internet on both networks?
Tried multiple combinations for creating the network, with external, bridge with custom config etc...

**Update**

After **larsks** answer, using `ip route add` for eth1 and running `tcpdump -i any` packets are coming in correctly:

```
11:26:12.098918 eth1  Out IP 8077ec32b69d > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 3, seq 1, length 64
11:26:12.184195 eth1  In  IP dns.google > 8077ec32b69d: ICMP echo reply, id 3, seq 1, length 64
```

But still 100% packet loss...

Comment: the name resolution works because the `-I` only affects the interface from which the ICMP Echo Req Packet (Ping) will be sent. anyway, maybe setup [NAT](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/html_single/Masquerading-Simple-HOWTO/), as the internal IP of the docker is unroutable. there might be a docker-specific solution but i'm not particularly familiar with dockers

Comment: The network name and interface name inside the container aren't the same thing.

Answer (score 9):

The problem here is that while there are two interfaces inside the container, there is only a single default route. Given a container with two interfaces, like this:

```
/ # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
70: eth0@if71: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:10:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.16.2/20 brd 192.168.31.255 scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
72: eth1@if73: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default
    link/ether 02:42:c0:a8:30:02 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff link-netnsid 0
    inet 192.168.48.2/20 brd 192.168.63.255 scope global eth1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

The routing table looks like this:

```
/ # ip route
default via 192.168.16.1 dev eth0
192.168.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.2
192.168.48.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.2
```

When you run `ping google.com` or `ping -I eth0 google.com`, in both
cases your ICMP request egresses through `eth0`, goes to the
appropriate default gateway, and eventually works it way to
google.com.

But when you run `ping -I eth1 google.com`, there's no way to reach
the default gateway from that address; the gateway is only reachable
via eth0. Since the kernel can't find a useful route, it attempts to
connect directly. If we run `tcpdump` on the host interface that is
the other end of with `eth1`, we see:

```
23:47:58.035853 ARP, Request who-has 142.251.35.174 tell 192.168.48.2, length 28
23:47:59.083553 ARP, Request who-has 142.251.35.174 tell 192.168.48.2, length 28
[...]
```

That's the kernel saying, "I've been told to connect to this address
using this specific interface, but there's no route, so I'm going to
assume the address is on the same network and just ARP for it".

Of course that fails.

We can make this work by adding an appropriate route. You need to run
a `privileged` container to do this (or at least have
`CAP_NET_ADMIN`):

```
ip route add default via 192.168.48.1 metric 101
```

(The gateway address is the `.1` address of the network associated with `eth1`.)

We need the `metric` setting to differentiate this from the existing
default route; without that the command would fail with `RTNETLINK answers: File exists`.

After running that command, we have:

```
/ # ip route
default via 192.168.16.1 dev eth0
default via 192.168.48.1 dev eth1 metric 101
192.168.16.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.16.2
192.168.48.0/20 dev eth1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.48.2
```

And we can successfully ping google.com via `eth1`:

```
/ # ping -c2 -I eth1 google.com
PING google.com (142.251.35.174) from 192.168.48.2 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=1 ttl=116 time=8.87 ms
64 bytes from lga25s78-in-f14.1e100.net (142.251.35.174): icmp_seq=2 ttl=116 time=8.13 ms

--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 1001ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 8.127/8.497/8.868/0.370 ms
```

---

Having gone through all that, I'll add that I don't see many
situations in which it would be necessary: typically you use
additional networks in order to isolate things like database servers,
etc, while using the "primary" interface (the one with which the
default route is associated) for outbound requests.

---

I tested all this using the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
version: "3"

services:
  sleeper:
    image: alpine
    cap_add:
      - NET_ADMIN
    command:
      - sleep
      - inf
    networks:
      - eth0
      - eth1

networks:
  eth0:
  eth1:
```

Comment: thanks for the detailed and quick response, I tried to recreate your solution, using tcpdump on the host it captures now the traffic, but the traffic not going back inside the container and ping have 100% packet loss

Comment: I know it's not really popular, but I'm using this because I want to demonstrate the architecture we have with multiple peers each connected to a different isp...

Comment: I just noticed that you're running under MacOS. That means Docker is running inside a Linux virtual machine. While that shouldn't impact this, I would want to look at traffic both from the macos host and from inside the linux vm to see where things are getting dropped.

Comment: I copied docker-compose.yaml together with `ip route add` (itself ran successfully), but it's not working on Windows&Ubuntu host. What does `101` mean ?
I don't have `192.168...` IP addresses inside docker, but `172.18.0.2/172.19.0.2`

Comment: Those addresses are based on the address assigned to `eth1` (I said this explicitly in the answer, "The gateway address is the .1 address of the network associated with eth1."). So if your `eth1` is `172.19.0.2`, the gateway for that network is going to be `172.19.0.1`.

Comment: Maybe thats the issue https://docs.docker.com/desktop/mac/networking/#i-cannot-ping-my-containers

Comment: @larsks Running tcpdump both on host and on the container show traffic IN/OUT not sure why it getting dropped after that, maybe something related to iptables –